# Loading Java Applet in Firefox on HTTPS

Tags: django, internet-explorer, firefox, https, applet

We have developed an analytics application that use a special Java applet (developed by IBM) to view some data. It’s a Django application that runs on Apache. Everything worked fine until we moved to SSL. The behavior is very strange and we are confused and a little bit worried how to make the applet work on HTTPS.
Ok, I have read many threads about security updates that were introduced in JRE 7u51 (Java JRE plugins) but I think that this is not the reason of our problems.

**My current environment is:**

- Firefox: version 27.0
- IE Explorer: version 10.0.12
- Apache: version 2.2
- SSL Certificate defined in Apache: Self signed certificates generated with openssl

**Running on HTTP :**
The Java applet runs on both browsers (Firefox, IE) and the data are displayed correctly.

**Running on HTTPS :**

A) IE Explorer: The Java applet runs with no errors and the data are displayed correctly.

B) Firefox:  ClassNotFoundException is thrown. Details:

```
    cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@499f7d
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1e95d95
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for https://demoapp.domain.com/s/ixv/i2Viewer.jar
security: Accessing keys and certificate in Mozilla user profile: null
security: JSS is not configured
basic: Loading Java Applet ...
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://demoapp.domain.com/s/ixv/i2Viewer.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting https://demoapp.domain.com/s/ixv/i2Viewer.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://demoapp.domain.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Checking if SSL certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://demoapp.domain.com/investigation/com/VDK/viewer/Chart.class, version: null]
network: Connecting https://demoapp.domain.com/investigation/com/VDK/viewer/Chart.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://demoapp.domain.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Checking if SSL certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://demoapp.domain.com/investigation/com/VDK/viewer/Chart/class.class, version: null]
network: Connecting https://demoapp.domain.com/investigation/com/VDK/viewer/Chart/class.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://demoapp.domain.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Checking if SSL certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.VDK.viewer.Chart.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: load: class com.VDK.viewer.Chart.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.VDK.viewer.Chart.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ignored exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.VDK.viewer.Chart.class
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1e95d95
security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

In the end I want to add that we had the same problems when running the applet with JRE 6 and without appropriate parameters in META-INF that are mandatory for JRE 7u51. So I think that the version of Java JRE (plugins version) is not the reason of our problems. What is more, the applet works perfectly on IE Explorer (HTTP and HTTPS).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message already gives the answer:

> Checking if SSL certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate
>   store

You said that you use a self signed certificate?
The reason might be that java (correctly) rejects the self signed certificate. Did you ensure that this certificate is in the java trust store? Java uses a different store for its certificate as the web browser. You can find it under System properties\Java\Security\Manage Certificates and there you are able to import your certificate...

Background info:

There are currently three truststores in that area:

- Windows System Certificate Store (which is also used by IE and Chrome)
- Firefox Certificate Store (I have read somewhere that they will switch to the windows certificate store in future, but don't know for sure)
- Java Certificate Store